# Python: Stuck in a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to create a guessing game where I have a variable that gets a random value and then a while loop that requires me to type in a number. This should go on until I get the same value as the random generated one and then print out a list with all the numbers that I typed in. For some reason the loop goes on and on even when I do get the same number.

This is my code so far:

```
import random

x = random.randint(1,10)
y = []
lst = []

while y != x:
    y = input('Your number:')
    lst.append(y)
    pass
print(lst)
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is no need for `pass` at the end of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: `input()` returns a string, so you have to convert it result to integer. Function `random.randint(1,10)` returns an integer number, so without converting `input()` function result to integer, condition `y != x` always will be True.

```
import random

x = random.randint(1,10)
y = None
lst = []

while y != x:
    y = int(input('Your number:'))
    lst.append(y)        
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your `x` variable into a string before comparing it to the `y` variable in the While loop. 
This works: (only change was adding the `str()` conversion to the `x` variable.)

```
import random

x = str(random.randint(1,10))
y = []
lst = []

while y != x:
    y = input('Your number:')
    lst.append(y)
    pass
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code x is an integer while y is a string. You need to convert your input (which is y) from the user to int. Simply do this to the code:

```
import random

x = random.randint(1,10)
y = []
lst = []

while y != x:
    y = int(input('Your number:'))
    lst.append(y)
    pass
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you are comparing type:int and type:str. "==" will always false. Here is how i did your program

```
import random

x = random.randint(1,10)
y = []
lst = []

while True:
  y = int(input('Your number:'))
  print(x)
  print(y)

 if(x==y):
   break
 else :
  lst.append(y) 
print(lst)
```